# Events are all showing the current date

Tags: date

I have installed lately the ACF plugin by Elliot Condon to manage my posted events on my website, I've put inside the WP_Query array the following:

```
<?php
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$homepageEvents = new WP_Query(array(
 'posts_per_page' => 2,           
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'orderBy' => 'meta_value_num',
 'meta_Key' => 'event_date',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_query' => array(
 array(
 'key' => 'event_date',
 'compare' => '>=',
 'value' => $today,
 'type' => 'numeric'
 )
)
));
```

and on my functions.php the following function:

```
function university_adjust_queries($query)
{
 if (!is_admin() and is_post_type_archive('event') and $query->is_main_query()) {                      //in order not to eleminate all the events in show all on backend
 $today = date('Y-m-d');
 //$query->set('posts_per_page', '1');                                                                    //these 3 queries written for the purpose of making the events by order in the archive page
 $query->set('meta_key', 'event_date');
 $query->set('orderBy', 'meta_value_num');
 $query->set('order', 'ASC');
 $query->set('meta_query', array(
 array(
 'key' => 'event_date',
 'compare' => '>=',
 'value' => $today,
 'type' => 'numeric'
 )
        ));
 }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'university_adjust_queries');
```

but my events on the frontend are all showing the same as (current date) even when i post them manually at the calendar on the backend.  any help please?